# My MacBook shows the screensaver seemingly forever! How do I tell it to just go blank after an hour or two without suspending the laptop?

Tags: macbook-pro, screensaver

For security reasons I have the screen on my MacBook set to lock after 1 minute of inactivity, at which point it displays the photos I've downloaded to it, but when I get up in the morning the screen is still on, still showing the photos.  This seems stupid, and is definitely not the behaviour I'm used to on my previous OS.

How can I set it to lock the screen after 5 minutes, and then turn the screen off after an hour.

I don't want it to suspend, since some things (containers and such) continue to run which don't need the screen.

Comment: I presume you have checked your settings in System Preferences > Energy Saver and have the option(s) set to "Turn display off after: [1 hour]" on both battery and power adapter tabs?

Comment: Well, I hadn't.  It doesn't appear by default, and there's no indication that I can find non-visible settinsg by typing in random counterintuitive phrases! Thanks for your suggestion - MacOS is so weird!

Comment: Everything is strange when new, don't worry, you'll find your way around soon enough. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Go into `System Preferences` and search for `Energy Saver` and (after you enter administrator privileges) you can change the settings to stop the display after some period of time.

Thanks @Steve Chambers for the detail - the `Energy Saver` settings aren't visible until you search for it.